# CSS Help - Responsive 2 columns becoming single column as screen is smaller

Tags: html, css, responsive

I don't post often, but I've been doing TONS of searching (and learning) and still can't figure out how to solve what I'm trying to do.

I created a jsfiddle that pretty much shows the issue I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/3pt2ks67/

What I would like to do (referencing the JSFiddle):

- Responsive CSS where I have left/right column, but when screen size is under 600px, stack left and right (that seems to work for the most part)
- Current issue: the left side, green, I would like the height of background-color to match the right column. the right column would always be longer, but of varying height
- Current issue: you see that in left/right mode (actually, also in stacked), the left+right columns are slightly smaller than the "Section Title" (red) - I would like them same width (90% of page width in total)
- Current issue: The footer is going all the way up to the Section Title, I would like it to have a space after the right column height - this seems to be proper when left/right are stacked

```css
.body {
  background-color: black;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;

}

.space {
  height: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.title {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">Header Menu</div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">Drop Down Selection</div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="title">Section Title</div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">This has a picture</div>
    <div class="right">This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words</div>
  </div>

  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer Menu</div>
</div>
```

I think this is my second post here as I can usually figure it out, but I'm looking for help from those who are way better than I am. Any help is appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, let me know if this is what you wanted:

```css
.body {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;

}


.space {
  height: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.title {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="header">Header Menu</div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">Drop Down Selection</div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="title">Section Title</div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">This has a picture</div>
    <div class="right">This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words</div>
  </div>

  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer Menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer. This seems to do what I want! I think I'm going to end up removing the 5px padding from the dropdown and title sections. With this solution, the title was still wider than the 2 columns combined. I played around with some CSS and couldn't get them to be the same width. After removing the padding, everything lines up. thank you again!

Comment: @radam I completely missed that part that you wanted. I've updated my answer to get those widths the same.  I simply removed the padding, but added a padding-top and padding-bottom of 5x for the title and dropdown. This should be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use flexbox to get your desired result. So try using the flexbox properties to make your left/right column display left and right with the same height.**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;

}

.space {
  height: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.title {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;

}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    
  }
  
  .left {        
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .right {
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="header">Header Menu</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="dropdown">Drop Down Selection</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="title">Section Title</div>
  
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">This has a picture</div>
      <div class="right">This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This 
      has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This 
      has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words<br>This 
      has a lot of words<br>This has a lot of words</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="footer">Footer Menu</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ezeilo, thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I think your answer got me part way there, but the footer wasn't to be seen and I didn't like the gap between columns. I chose a different answer as that got me to where I need. But again, I appreciate you taking the time to help out. thank you!

Comment: @radam, I  have adjusted  the space between the columns by increasing the width of the left/right column...